# React Router history.push is updated when I scroll through images inside the component, but the route doesn't actually change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a component that scrolls through images on click. When I click the back button that implements `history.goBack()` it should take me back to the main page, however it cycles back through the images and I have to click multiple times to actually get back. I thought this was due to using store and the component updating and causing `history.push` to push the current location onto to the stack and then causing me to have to cycle back through the stack, but after removing store the problem still persists. Is there a way to keep react router history from updating if the `pathname` doesn't change?

Comment: Can you share your code or a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by a simple condition checking before you execute your `history.push('/path')` command.

```js
if (history.location.pathname !== '/path_you_are_about_to_push') {
    history.push('/path_you_are_about_to_push');
}
```

It will prevent unnecessary piling up of route history. `history.location.pathname` is a string of your current route path. You can go [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history) to study more about `history` properties and methods.